Property [codigo] does not exist on this collection instance
He visto que hay preguntas similares pero despues de revisaras, no consigo solucionar mi problema.
Tengo 2 tablas:
Tabla Proyectos (codigo, nombre, direccion, poblacion, cp, promotor, arquitecto, id_fase)
Tabla Fase (id, tipo)
La tabla fase puede tener muchos proyectos, pero cada proyecto solo tiene una fase.
estos son los modelos
        class Proyecto extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
    
        public function fases(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Fase::class, 'id_fase');
        }
    }
    
    class Fase extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
    
        public function proyectos(){
            return $this->hasMany(Proyecto::class, 'id');
        }
    
    }

este es el controller, solo pongo el edit que es el que me da error:
    public function edit(Proyecto $codigo)
    {
        $proyecto = Proyecto::find($codigo);
        $fases = Fase::all();
        return view('proyecto.edit')->with('proyecto',$proyecto)->with('fases', $fases);
    }

por ultimo, este es el edit.blade.php
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="" class="form-label">Codigo proyecto</label>
        <input id="codigo" name="codigo" type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="1" value="{{$proyecto->codigo}}" readonly>
    </div>

no se porque me dice que no existe, he hecho lo mismo para el index y si que funciona.
gracias por la ayuda

he encontrado la respuesta a mi pregunta.
tenia que poner esto en el model ya que habia cambiado el nombre del primary key
    public function getKeyName(){
        return "codigo";
    }


Es importante mencionar que el error era provocado porque Laravel trabaja con ciertas convecciones. Laravel siempre va a buscar por defecto el primary key nombrado como "id" (porque esta es la convención), a menos que lo especifiques como lo hiciste.
